# Add multiple collection objects values for equal keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple objects in a collection instance having same keys but different values. I need a way to add quantity field key values in the same objects.

```
[
    0 => {
      +"product_id": 1
      +"quantity": "50"
      +"price": "25.00"
    },
    1 => {
      +"product_id": 3
      +"quantity": "50"
      +"price": "75.00"
    },
    2 => {
      +"product_id": 2
      +"quantity": "50"
      +"price": "50.00"
    },
    3 => {
      +"product_id": 3
      +"quantity": "50"
      +"price": "75.00"
    }    
]
```

Resulting Instance should have the quantities added in the same item keys as follows.

```
[
    0 => {
      +"product_id": 1
      +"quantity": "50"
      +"price": "25.00"
    },
    1 => {
      +"product_id": 2
      +"quantity": "50"
      +"price": "50.00"
    }
    2 => {
      +"product_id": 3
      +"quantity": "100"
      +"price": "75.00"
    }
]
```

I have tried to iterate through all the objects and add/edit object as follows. I'm not sure whether this is the best practice way in a Laravel collection.

```
$newItems = [];

$items->each(function ($item, $key) use ($newItems) {
    $existId = array_column($newItems, 'id');
    if($existId){
        // add quantity to the existing item
    } else {
        // push item to items array
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a little sidenote: It seems like in your last code block you use `$items` for what should be 2 different variables and because of it you'll get the error that `each` doesn't exist on an array.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper sorry, It was a typo

Comment: It appears again in `use ($items)` and `array_column($items` ;)

Comment: @camille are your problem solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#available-methods) [`reduce`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-reduce) to create a new collection where you either add items that aren't in the new collection yet, or sum up their quantities:

```php
$total = $items->reduce(
  // The function that will insert or add the items together.
  function ($carry, $item) {
    if ($carry->has($item->product_id)) {
      $carry[$item->product_id]->quantity += $item->quantity;
    } else {
      $carry[$item->product_id] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
  }, 
  // The initial empty collection that will be filled up every iteration.
  collect([])
);
```